# Update value in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How can I update the value from another component and update it in Dom?

page Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

EmName = null
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,) {}

ngOnInit() {
 

  this.EmName = "jo"

}

ChangeValue(){
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/change');
}
    
   ch(){
     this.EmName = "New Val"
     console.log(this.EmName)
   }
  
}
```

page change.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change',
  templateUrl: './change.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change.page.scss'],
})
export class ChangePage implements OnInit {


constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,private homePage:HomePage ){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  next() {
    this.navCtrl.pop()
  this.homePage.ch()
    }
}
```

The variable value is updated, but the display is not updated as in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaJ2V.png)

I am a beginner and I need help thank you.

Comment: can you please share html code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to force the view to update. With NgZone of **@angular/core** you can do that. For that, I saw a solution through this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-properly-re-render-a-component-in-ionic-manually/97343

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you has been done...

Depending on this solution
Sharing Data with a Service

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  message:string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

sibling.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  message:string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```

I repeat my thanks to all of you.